# Auto-publish images once they are uploaded

Tags: library, picture-library

Is there a way to publish images and documents automatically once they are uploaded to a library? Without customization or coding.

Comment: Disable the versioning settings on the library so there is no major/minor versioning or need to publish them and disable content approval?

Comment: Thanks, It seems that there is no auto publish feature in SharePoint to make files be published directly after they are uploaded.

Comment: As Eric stated, auto-publish makes no sense when you can simply disable approva and minor versionsl: without approval an minor versions, it's exactly like your images were "auto-published"...

Comment: If you REALLY want to auto-publish (which, as above doesn't make much sense when you can just turn it off) it would require a simple workflow.